# How to catch this exception C++

Tags: c++, exception, cin

I'd like to catch exception which occurs when somebody gives not a number value on the cin so the program will read next value.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    while(true){
        cin >> x;
        cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use exception handling, you could do something like this:

```
cin.exceptions(ios_base::failbit); // throw on rejected input
try {
// some code
int choice;
cin >> choice;
// some more code
} catch(const ios_base::failure& e) {
    cout << "What was that?\n";
    break;
}
```

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/71540/

Answer (score 4):

There is no exception being thrown at all. Instead, `cin` sets a "bad input" flag of sorts. What you want is this:

```
while ((std::cout << "Enter input: ") && !(std::cin >> x)) {
    std::cin.clear(); //clear the flag
    std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //discard the bad input
    std::cout << "Invalid input; please re-enter.\n";
}
```

[This series of questions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.3) explains it really well.

Links:
[`clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear)
[`ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)

Answer (score 2):

Add something like:

```
if(cin.fail())
{   
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),' '); 
  cout << "Please enter valid input";
}
```

Comment: For @KonradRudolph: replace `cin.ignore(256,' ');` with `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),' ');`

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    cin.exceptions(ios::failbit);
    while(true){
        try
        {
            cin>>x;
        }
        catch(ios_base::failure& e)
        {
            //..
        }
        cout<<"x = "<<x<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This should work.